# Read special characters back from XmlDocument in c#

Tags: c#, xml, xmldocument

Say I have the an xml with a escaped ampersand (&). How do I then read it back such that the result gives me the 'un-escaped' text.

Running the following gives me **"&amp"**  as the result. How do I get back **'&'**

```
void Main()
{
  var xml = @"
  <a>
    &amp;
  </a>
  ";
  var doc = new XmlDocument();
  doc.LoadXml(xml);
  var ele = (XmlElement)doc.FirstChild;
  Console.WriteLine (ele.InnerXml); 
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use **ele.InnerText** instead of **ele.InnerXml**

Answer (score 1):

you can use CDATA in order to get your data

Characters like "<" and "&" are illegal in XML elements."<"  the parser interprets it as the start of a new element. "&" the parser interprets it as the start of an character entity.

Answer (score 0):

```
use
 HttpServerUtility.HtmlDecode (ele.InnerXml);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Console.WriteLine (HttpUtility.UrlDecode(String.Format("{0}",ele.InnerXml)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this static method to decode escaped characters:
HttpServerUtility.HtmlDecode Method (String)
See example here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/hwzhtkke.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The following characters are illegal in XML elements:

```
Illegal EscapedUsed
------------------
    "   &quot;
    '   &apos;
    <   &lt;
    >   &gt;
    &   &amp;
```

To get the unescaped value you can use:

```
 public string UnescapeXMLValue(string xmlValue)
  {
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(s)) return s;
   string temp = s;
   temp = temp.Replace("&apos;", "'").Replace("&quot;", "\"").Replace("&gt;", ">").Replace("&lt;", "<").Replace("&amp;", "&");
   return temp ;
 }
```

To get the escaped value you can use:

```
public string EscapeXMLValue(string value)
  {
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(s)) return s;
   string temp = s;
   temp = temp.Replace("'","&apos;").Replace( "\"", "&quot;").Replace(">","&gt;").Replace( "<","&lt;").Replace( "&","&amp;");
   return temp ;
 }
```